# Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'electric bus 0' was passed

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, group-by

i am working with this software called PyPSA(Python for energy system Analysis).

I am writing a small code to create so busses for power transport. However when i input multiple values using this special function called `.madd()`. (`Network.madd(class_name, names, suffix='', **kwargs`). I get an error. I am beginner at python program .

```
n = pypsa.Network()

for i in range(3):
    n.madd("Bus","electric bus {}".format(i),v_nom=20, x=x_value, y=y_value)
print(n.buses)
```

```
TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'electric bus 0' was passed
```

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38599912/index-must-be-called-with-a-collection-of-some-kind-assign-column-name-to-dataf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Index must be called with a collection of some kind: assign column name to dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38599912/index-must-be-called-with-a-collection-of-some-kind-assign-column-name-to-dataf)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that PyPSA however according to the [documentation](https://pypsa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/import_export.html?highlight=madd#pypsa.Network.madd) as *names* (2nd argument) you should provide a list or pandas.Index object

I'm assuming you should move this for loop to the parameter itself and create a list there. Like that:

```python
n.madd("Bus",[F"electric bus {x}" for x in range(3)], v_nom=20, x=x_value, y=y_value)
```

Not sure if F notation works with your python version, so you can also do this

```python
n.madd("Bus",["electric bus {}".format(x) for x in range(3)], v_nom=20, x=x_value, y=y_value)
```

Comment: If the answer is correct, you can mark the answer as correct